# Linear dependence of vectors in 3-D

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I read in a book that any 4 vectors in 3-dimensional space are linearly dependent. 
But what if first and second vectors are parallel and fourth vector does not lie in plane formed by first,second and third vector, then shouldn't the vectors be linearly independent?

Comment: Then the first two are linearly dependent.